# How to get closest date by day of week?

Tags: php, laravel, date

I have the weekdays from 1 to 7 (Monday to Sunday).

I want to get the next date, where the day is the specified day (from 1 to 7).

For example, today is 25.09.2018.

When I pass 5 (Friday) I want to get 28.09.2018 which is the next closest Friday.

How can I achieve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Example for Friday(5)

```
Carbon::now()
    ->next(5)
    ->toDateString();
```

[More about Carbon library](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 3):

See [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime)

```
`strtotime('next tuesday');`
```

You could probably find out using strtotime:

`echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime('next friday'));`

Answer (score 1):

Without using Carbon

```
$date = new \DateTimeImmutable();

$nextFriday = $date->sub(new \DateInterval("P".$date->format("w")."D"))->add(new \DateInterval("P5D"));
```

Answer (score 1):

- Find the given date's week day number
- Calculate the days to add. First, find the number of days to reach weekend (7 - current week day number). Then, add the given input.
- Use `date` and `strtotime` functions, to get the resultant date.

Try the following (explanation in code comments):

```
// Get weekday number for current date (or, you can use any other given date)
$start_date = time();
$weekday = (int)date('w', $start_date);

// assuming $input eg: 5 (Friday)
// calculating the differential we need to add 
$diff = (7 - $weekday) + $input;

$new_date = date(strtotime($start_date . "+" . $diff . " day"));
```

Answer (score 1):

with `strtotime` you can get the next friday like this `strtotime('next friday')`

so in PHP something like this might work:

```
date('d.m.Y', strtotime("next friday"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is custom generic function you can use anywhere,

```
function getNextDate($date, $number)
{
    $numericDay = (($number - 1) <= 0 ? 0 : $number - 1);
    $day        = jddayofweek($numericDay, 1);
    echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime("next " . $day . "", strtotime($date)));
}
getNextDate("25.09.2018", 5);
```

This function you can use as generic function too.

You will get clear idea about [jddayofweek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php).

I passed 1 as Returns string containing the day of week (English-Gregorian).

I substracted 1 as Monday is considered as first index by default.